# Make the recycle bin of the SSD on a RAID0 drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, batch, speed

I don't know about you folks, but I hate the idea of junk sitting on my tiny 30GB SSD. Any way to designate another drive to be the host of the Recycle Bin for items formerly on the SSD?

Basically, I need to know how to make a lower-priority drive receive the recycled materials from the 'main' drive, which happens to be short on space.

The best thing I can think of is a batch file that a) syncs 'recycle' to another drive; and b) empties the recycle bin. ... but that's too much work for me.

Comment: Good question. I don't think there is an easy way, since each partition has its own recycle bin. Maybe windows will move files automatically to another recycle bin if you decrease the size for partition with SSD? I'm trying to check that out right now.

Comment: Well, that didn't work. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Recycle Bin is created on the SAME partition as the data you're trying to delete, unless it's a removable drive, in which case no Recycle Bin is created.

In other words, deleting a file into the Recycle Bin is just a move and rename operation, nothing more. The Recycle Bin doesn't actually exist as a physical location, so moving it would not be possible.

Try doing something different, like moving your page file, or compressing folders, or moving your User folder to a different drive. That makes more sense.